# Is drawing straight lines in paint using SHIFT and mouse dragging an example of multithreading?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am studying multi-threading and now I am stuck. I read that **Multi-threading in java is a process of executing multiple threads simultaneously**. What does this **'simultaneously'** mean? Also, multi-threading is based upon the concept of time-sharing, so how can the threads execute simultaneously? And if threads can't execute simultaneously, then how are we able to draw straight lines in paint by holding the shift key and dragging the mouse at the same time?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask), [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask), and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic) This is **far** too broad for SO. Find some threading and concurrent programming tutorials and books. (The answer to the question in your title is: No. It doesn't take a thread to remember the state of a key.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short overview:

Indeed most Threads do not run at the same time. The trick is that threads switch often between one another. This gives the illusion of parallelism. (Similar to how images in quick succession give the illusion of continuous motion, quickly changing threads give the illusion of running at the same time)

How paint is implemented is anyone's guess. Here goes mine:

You press shift, a boolean flag gets raised

You move your mouse, the line is calculated

If you raise the shift key the bool flag is switched, causing the line not to be straight anymore

Ideed, key listening is an action that often is multithreaded. You have a thread that just asks all keys every few milliseconds if they were pressed. If so it sends a message to other treads (if they are listening for that particular key). The same goes for reading mouse movement.

Usually, you do not have to go in great detail for IO, as it is handled by most librarys/ frameworks for you. Also IO requires OS support, so that opens a new can of worms

I hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

Processor can't execute several threads at one time, so threads are executing pseudo-simultaneously. [image]

At this picture each color means each thread. Processor execute one thread then second etc. It seems like they are executing sumultaneously, but probably processor just change current thread and execute this.

Comment: if threads can't execute simultaneously, then how are we able to draw straight lines in paint by holding the shift key and dragging the mouse at the same time?